# Не могу выбрать ближайший элемент и открыть его с помощью клика, в чем причина?

Tags: javascript

При клике на ссылку должно появляться ближайшее спрятанное окно

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.catalog_section__a').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.catalog_section_cell').find('.catalog_section_popup').show();
    });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код свой пожалуйста добавьте, а то гадать сложно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По jQuery все верно, кроме того, что не плохо бы сделать e.preventDefault(). Проблемы могут возникнуть, только в разметке HTML, так как в кликабельной ссылке у Вас пустота, возможно лучше туда поместить картинку или текст. Ну и, конечно, надо смотреть CSS стили для ссылки, заданы ли для нее размеры

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.catalog_section__a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find($('.catalog_section_popup')).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.catalog_section_popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog_section_cell">
  <div class="catalog_section_popup">catalog_section_popup</div>
  <div>
    <div class="catalog_section__a">catalog_section__a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не помогло к сожалению((

Comment: работает, я не сразу разобрался в вашей разметке. Вы впредь если вопрос какой код не снепшотте а копипасте.

Comment: Не, нифига, что то вообще не то((

Comment: Да, фига, вообще то

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.catalog_section__a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.catalog_section_cell').find('.catalog_section_popup').show();
  });
});
```